# two bootstrap navbar need to collapse on

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Hi i have a two bootstrap navs , i need when the user view the website on mobile , the two navbars  appear on one collapse , how can i achieve that
also betwen collapsed search and social buttons , there is border , i cant remove the borders
here is the code that i been working on ( link to codepin https://codepen.io/touilahmedimad/pen/yLJdObz

```
<body><div class="navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Navbar Header [collects both toggle button and navbar brand] -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- Toggle Button [handles opening navbar menu on mobile screens]-->
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exampleNavComponents" aria-expanded "false">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></i>
                    </button>

        <!-- Navbar Brand -->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                        Navbar
                    </a>
      </div>


      <!-- Navbar Collapse [collect navbar components such as navbar links and forms ] -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="exampleNavComponents">

        <!-- Navbar Links -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-expand" style="display: inline-flex;">
          <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light">
                                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light">
                                    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light">
                                    <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light">
                                    <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light">
                                    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Navbar Form -->
        <form action="#" class="navbar-form navbar-right">

       <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>

       

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="exampleNavComponents">
 <nav class=" navbar-default  ">
   <ul class="nav  navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 navbarc ">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">War on crimes </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li><li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li><li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li><li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repudiandae sapiente explicabo aperiam veritatis adipisci, omnis debitis sint quaerat soluta necessitatibus, dolore accusamus aut neque ab? Non praesentium maxime perferendis!</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique iusto aspernatur eius a blanditiis eveniet ullam et itaque, esse rem fuga voluptate voluptatibus voluptatum, tempore obcaecati praesentium ad quo sunt.</span><span>Velit optio quidem qui nam quia eius obcaecati dolor eligendi facere tempore, ratione rem inventore nobis maxime sit reiciendis placeat dolores ad recusandae porro. Omnis rerum similique quo voluptate incidunt!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita nam voluptate sed explicabo, ut adipisci dolore omnis. Facilis veniam natus quae, alias sapiente. Explicabo maxime eligendi maiores quisquam ipsam, omnis!</span>
        <span>Consequuntur odit, assumenda soluta voluptatibus earum quasi, ipsa est natus quae facilis aliquid sint. Fugiat illum eum quis fuga id totam molestiae, itaque reprehenderit et iusto voluptatum similique facilis doloremque.</span>
        <span>Pariatur quibusdam nesciunt explicabo ea saepe, at atque aut iste vel quis et, quos nam itaque magni assumenda libero amet corrupti architecto doloremque voluptatem neque doloribus qui non unde. Doloribus.</span>
        <span>Architecto id, error nobis. Vel quibusdam, eius aut deserunt sed omnis necessitatibus ab iusto eveniet, tenetur tempore a nobis illum quia optio est excepturi adipisci doloribus quidem? Animi, officiis repellendus!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repudiandae sapiente explicabo aperiam veritatis adipisci, omnis debitis sint quaerat soluta necessitatibus, dolore accusamus aut neque ab? Non praesentium maxime perferendis!</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique iusto aspernatur eius a blanditiis eveniet ullam et itaque, esse rem fuga voluptate voluptatibus voluptatum, tempore obcaecati praesentium ad quo sunt.</span><span>Velit optio quidem qui nam quia eius obcaecati dolor eligendi facere tempore, ratione rem inventore nobis maxime sit reiciendis placeat dolores ad recusandae porro. Omnis rerum similique quo voluptate incidunt!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita nam voluptate sed explicabo, ut adipisci dolore omnis. Facilis veniam natus quae, alias sapiente. Explicabo maxime eligendi maiores quisquam ipsam, omnis!</span>
        <span>Consequuntur odit, assumenda soluta voluptatibus earum quasi, ipsa est natus quae facilis aliquid sint. Fugiat illum eum quis fuga id totam molestiae, itaque reprehenderit et iusto voluptatum similique facilis doloremque.</span>
        <span>Pariatur quibusdam nesciunt explicabo ea saepe, at atque aut iste vel quis et, quos nam itaque magni assumenda libero amet corrupti architecto doloremque voluptatem neque doloribus qui non unde. Doloribus.</span>
        <span>Architecto id, error nobis. Vel quibusdam, eius aut deserunt sed omnis necessitatibus ab iusto eveniet, tenetur tempore a nobis illum quia optio est excepturi adipisci doloribus quidem? Animi, officiis repellendus!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repudiandae sapiente explicabo aperiam veritatis adipisci, omnis debitis sint quaerat soluta necessitatibus, dolore accusamus aut neque ab? Non praesentium maxime perferendis!</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique iusto aspernatur eius a blanditiis eveniet ullam et itaque, esse rem fuga voluptate voluptatibus voluptatum, tempore obcaecati praesentium ad quo sunt.</span><span>Velit optio quidem qui nam quia eius obcaecati dolor eligendi facere tempore, ratione rem inventore nobis maxime sit reiciendis placeat dolores ad recusandae porro. Omnis rerum similique quo voluptate incidunt!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita nam voluptate sed explicabo, ut adipisci dolore omnis. Facilis veniam natus quae, alias sapiente. Explicabo maxime eligendi maiores quisquam ipsam, omnis!</span>
        <span>Consequuntur odit, assumenda soluta voluptatibus earum quasi, ipsa est natus quae facilis aliquid sint. Fugiat illum eum quis fuga id totam molestiae, itaque reprehenderit et iusto voluptatum similique facilis doloremque.</span>
        <span>Pariatur quibusdam nesciunt explicabo ea saepe, at atque aut iste vel quis et, quos nam itaque magni assumenda libero amet corrupti architecto doloremque voluptatem neque doloribus qui non unde. Doloribus.</span>
        <span>Architecto id, error nobis. Vel quibusdam, eius aut deserunt sed omnis necessitatibus ab iusto eveniet, tenetur tempore a nobis illum quia optio est excepturi adipisci doloribus quidem? Animi, officiis repellendus!</span>
      </p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit repudiandae sapiente explicabo aperiam veritatis adipisci, omnis debitis sint quaerat soluta necessitatibus, dolore accusamus aut neque ab? Non praesentium maxime perferendis!</p>

      <div class="line"></div>

      <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique iusto aspernatur eius a blanditiis eveniet ullam et itaque, esse rem fuga voluptate voluptatibus voluptatum, tempore obcaecati praesentium ad quo sunt.</span><span>Velit optio quidem qui nam quia eius obcaecati dolor eligendi facere tempore, ratione rem inventore nobis maxime sit reiciendis placeat dolores ad recusandae porro. Omnis rerum similique quo voluptate incidunt!</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

css

```
    /* ==========================================================
        General Demo Styles [not related to navbar]
   ==========================================================*/
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #555;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

/* ==========================================================
        Navbar Styles
   ==========================================================*/
.navbar {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: #333;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.navbar a {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar button {
  color: inherit !important;
}

.navbar.compressed {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  color: #6dcc7c;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.navbarc {
  width: 100%;
 backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution , is to to target on toggle  button

```
data-target=".navbars"
```

and add class "navbar" to the two navbars

```
<div class="navbar-collapse navbars collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
```

here is the pin with the solution implemented [Pin](https://codepen.io/touilahmedimad/pen/yLJdObz)